# Computer always says I'm wrong - random.randint question

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to make a random Guess the Number game with a simple points system. The thing is I'm going through the code again and again and I don't see what the problem is. The thing is the computer always says I'm wrong, I never win and I even tried using `random.randint(1,2)` but nothing. I usually have bad luck but I'm  pretty sure it's the code not working.

```
import random

print("Guess the number from 1 to 10")

while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 2)
    number = int(number)
    guess = input("Enter number: ")
    points = 0
    if number == guess:
        print("You guessed right!")
        points += 1
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong guess")

print("You have: " + str(points) + " points.")

print("Wanna try again? ")
tryagain = input("Y or N: ")
if tryagain == "Y" or "y":
    continue
else:
    break
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning: `number = int(number)` isn't doing anything, as `randint()` returns an `int` already

Answer (score 0):

It is because your "guess" variable is still recognized as a **string** and will not be recognized as equal to your **integer** "number" variable.

Change your `if number == guess:` to `if number == int(guess):`

After you change that it should work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you forgot to change the guess to an `int`. You also made it so that the points reset to zero every round; the points=0 statement should occur outside of the loop.

Here's a working version of your script:

```
import random 

print("Guess the number from 1 to 10")
points = 0

while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 2)   # no need for "int"
#     print(number) # uncomment to cheat 
    guess = input("Enter number: ")
    if int(guess) == number:
        print("You guessed right!")
        points += 1
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong guess")

    print("You have: " + str(points) + " points.")

    print("Wanna try again? ")
    tryagain = input("Y or N: ")
    if tryagain.upper() == "N": # you only do something *different* in the N case
        break
```

You can also shorten the code a bit further since you don't need to use the user input outside of the if statements.

```
import random


print("Guess the number from 1 to 10")
points = 0

while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 2)   # no need for "int"
#     print(number) # uncomment to cheat 
    if int(input("Enter number: ")) == number:
        print("You guessed right!")
        points += 1
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong guess")

    print("You have: %s points."%points)

    print("Wanna try again? ") 
    if input("Y or N: ").upper() == "N": # you only do something *different* in the N case
        break
```

Comment: thank you! i cant upvote yet because im new to StackOverflow but i was also having troubles with the points system, thanks!

Comment: No problem! If that solves your problem, then please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote buttons to the left of my answer.